# AFNetworking Post error

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

i'm trying to send a POST request where i have 2 parameters and then will get a json object back. I'm using AFNetworking and i get this error everytime:

```
Error: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: not found (404)" UserInfo=0x16d93980 {com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.response=  <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x16d8f0d0> { URL: http://LINK } { status code: 404, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 285;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
    Date = "Fri, 11 Jul 2014 16:43:42 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=99";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.9 (Ubuntu)";
} }, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://LINK, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: not found (404),     NSUnderlyingError=0x16d8f880 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html"}
```

POST Objective-c request

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager POST:@"LINK"

   parameters:@{@"number": storeID, @"udid" : [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString}
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
          NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
      } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
      }];


NSLog(@"%@ = %@", storeID, [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString);
```

php script for testing

```
    $var = $_POST["number"];
    $udid = $_POST["udid"];

     echo '{"match": 1}';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AFHTTPRequestOperationManager serializer expects a json content type. But your PHP peer responded it as html.

Try this in your PHP:

```
$var = $_POST["number"];
$udid = $_POST["udid"];

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo '{"match": 1}';
```

Alternatively, you can set other serializer to your manager and parse the response manually:

```
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
```